# Why does Nikon (e.g. D5100) use Hi1 and Hi2 instead of numeric ISO settings?

Tags: iso, high-iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “expanded ISO” mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/what-does-expanded-iso-mean)

Are these settings real sensitivity options when reading the CMOS sensor or just after-processing what can be done outside the camera as well? (Of course working with RAW format outside the camera).

Speculative additional question: if real then why not just call them ISO6400 and ISO12800?